# Going back to client during a post request for confirmation in a web api

Tags: c#, httprequest, asp.net-web-api2

I am sending a post request to my API for analyzing and updating many objects. when this update is finalized I would like to send back the user a confirmation to enter an approval code and commit the changes.

I am not sure how to do this. Is there a way to await/preserve the state the of the request and continue to commit when the user sends the approval code ?

Comment: You wouldn't want to do this at the request level.  "Commit" the data to a server-side data store, but not necessarily in a "business committed" state.  (A temporary location?  The same location but with some kind of flag indicating it's in a "pending" status?)  When the user "approves" the operation, then update the data.

Comment: Is there a local storage functionality/mechanism in a web api controller ? @David

Comment: ASP.NET allows you to store in session state, but depending on what you're storing that might not be the best idea.  Ideally you'd commit to some non-volatile storage medium.  Keeping large amounts of data in application memory doesn't scale well.

Comment: Usual flow is: Client makes request, server processes request and replies with a response. So you could use this mechanism if the client can wait while you do the update. I'd only *not* use it, if the update takes a very long time or has low priority, in which case you could reply with a response that the update was queued. In that case there is no mechanism to send the update to the client. The only ways to achieve that is to keep a socket open while you wait, or make the client poll periodically to check the state.

Comment: To add to David's comment about session state.  There is a strategy available that allows you to use a database server to store session state.  That alleviates the application memory problem, and allows sessions to  survive a site re-start.